# What is the difference between `extends` and `rulesDirectory` in TSLint

Tags: typescript, eslint, lint, tslint

The TSLint.json config file (https://github.com/palantir/tslint) supports `extends` and a `rulesDirectory` array like so

```js
{
  "extends": [
    "tslint-microsoft-contrib",
    "tslint-config-security"
  ],
  "rulesDirectory": [
    "node_modules/tslint-eslint-rules/dist/rules",
    "node_modules/tslint-microsoft-contrib",
    "node_modules/tslint-config-security"
  ]
}
```

The docs seem slightly open to interpretation for new users unfamiliar to the tool.

I would appreciate if anyone could clarify a few points on the behaviour of `extends` and `rulesDirectory` in relation to use in the VS Code editor and `tslint`ing in general.

1. Does `extends` **only** provide a default configuration (if provided by package)?
2. and is this therefore different to `rulesDirectory`?

   - Does `rulesDirectory` only provide rules for you to specifically opt-in(and is required if specifying rules in the root tslint.json)?
   - Should I still specify the `tslint` packages in both `extends` ***and*** `rulesDirectory`?
3. Assuming `extends` provides defaults from another `tslint` config file, would I be able to specify the `rulesDirectory` and add a rule to override a specific flag?

Concerned because only some of the rules show up in IntelliSense autocompletion and just a few behaviours that I would appreciate more clarity for.

Comment: ^V Please comment why you have down-voted so I can improve the question to your liking.

Comment: The `extends` configuration option extends the `tslint.json` configuration in the named package **and** makes available the rules in the named package. Whether or not the package's `tslint.json` enables any of its rules be default is a decision for the package author. I have several TSLint packages that provide default configurations that have no rules enabled, so using `extend` simply makes the packages' rules available in a more concise manner than specifying paths to the packages' rules directories.

Comment: Thanks @cartant for the comprehensive answer! So I can safely remove the `rulesDirectory`? Also, Does your IDE autocomplete work for your packages' rules when adding them in? I see your work on `TSLint`ing `RxJS`. I wish I had noticed that earlier when I was trying to sort out different `RxJS` versions while learning! *I would happily accept your answer for this question*

Comment: No. I use VS Code and, AFAICT, it only autocompletes the built-in rules. It's not something that I've looked into and it's not something I've ever relied upon. The rules in my packages include the required metadata - it's in the rules' code - but what's behind the autocompletion and whether or not it requires something in addition to the metadata, I have no idea.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your assistance. I really appreciate it. I'll just stick to specifying the rules for now .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is the difference between `extends` and `rulesDirectory` in TSLint

They are very different.

- `extends` allows you to apply an existing tslint config and then extend it
- `rulesDirectory` simply allows you to add directories for custom rules.

Comment: I do not get the differences at all... You write they are very different, but as you describe, in both cases, they just add custom rules from a package. Once those custom rules come from a config file and the other way, they come from a directoy. So I would say, they are pretty much the same, but the way they are added is a bit different (config file vs directory).

Answer (score 2):

?Answer taken from [tslint configuration docs as of 6 April 2018](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/f904497838747854f6333fb02c4849b6538b09b9/docs/usage/configuration/index.md):

> - `extends?: string | string[]`: The name of a built-in configuration preset (see built-in presets below), or a path or array of paths to
>     other configuration files which are extended by this configuration.
>     This value is handled using node module resolution semantics. For
>     example, a value of `"tslint-config"` would tell TSLint to try and
>     load the main file of a module named "tslint-config" as a
>     configuration file. Specific files inside node modules can also be
>     specified, eg. `"tslint-config/path/to/submodule"`. Relative paths to
>     JSON files or JS modules are also supported, e.g. `"./tslint-config"`.
> - `rulesDirectory?: string | string[]`: A path to a directory or an array of paths to directories of [custom rules][2]. These values are
>     handled using node module resolution semantics, if an `index.js` is
>     placed in your rules directory. We fallback to use relative or
>     absolute paths, if the module can't be resolved. If you want to avoid
>     module resolution you can directly use a relative or absolute path
>     (e.g. with `./`).

Any rules specified in this `rules` block will override those configured in any base configuration being extended.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [docs](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/configuration/).

Seems the main difference is:

- `"extends"` uses sets of **build-in** rules
- `"rulesDirectory"` uses [**custom**](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/develop/custom-rules/) (your own, not build-in) rules